# PHP Mysql Get Gap between time range

Tags: php, mysql, time, difference-between-rows

Im kinda new here in stackoverflow. Anyway here is my problem, hope someone could help me on this.
I have a table in mysql see below

```
Start Time         End Time         Date
 9:00               10:00           2016-02-26
 9:00               10:00           2016-02-25
 11:00              12:00           2016-02-25
 12:00              13:00           2016-02-25
 13:00              14:00           2016-02-25
 15:00              16:00           2016-02-25
```

what I want to get is the gap between those time with specific date. See below for my desired output:

```
Start Time         End Time        Date
 10:00               11:00         2016-02-25
 14:00               15:00         2016-02-25
```

Please if someone know the answer, it would be a big help. Thanks

Comment: ie you want the endtime-starttime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```sql
SELECT gap_start, gap_end
FROM (
  SELECT (SELECT EndTime
         FROM mytable AS t2
         WHERE t2.EndTime < t1.StartTime
         ORDER BY t2.EndTime DESC LIMIT 1) AS gap_start,
         StartTime AS gap_end
  FROM mytable AS t1) AS t
WHERE gap_start IS NOT NULL
```

The correlated subquery used will fetch the `StartTime` of the records that immediately precedes the current record. Here it is assumed that there is *always* a gap between consecutive records.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e0074/5)

**Edit:**

The query can be modified like as follows in order to handle the addition of a `Date` field:

```sql
SELECT gap_start, gap_end, `Date`
FROM (
  SELECT (SELECT EndTime
          FROM mytable AS t2
          WHERE t2.`Date` <= t1.`Date` AND t2.EndTime <= t1.StartTime
          ORDER BY t2.`Date` DESC, t2.EndTime DESC LIMIT 1) AS gap_start,
         StartTime AS gap_end,
         `Date`
  FROM mytable AS t1) AS t
WHERE gap_start IS NOT NULL AND gap_start < gap_end
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91d8c/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Works pretty well. you saved my day. Thanks for quick response. Have a nice day :))))))

Comment: sorry bro but I have to unaccept the answer. Its might be simple solution for you guys but big problem for me. I found out that it keeps on showing the times which is less the StartTime. please look at revise example above for more details. Thanks much

Comment: Thanks again @GiorgosBetsos, I didnt knew that's how simple it is. thanks thanks thanks :)